# oauth 401 error

Tags: php, oauth

Пытаюсь использовать oAuth для получения данных через API etsy.com
Делал все по их [инструкции](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth):

Получил:

```
<?php
        $conskey = 'm4cztdgpbparyv8223hyxdoqw';
        $conssec = '63fur1wp9on';
        $oauth = new OAuth($conskey, $conssec, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
        $req_token = $oauth->getRequestToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20transactions_r&profile_r&address_r", 'oob', "GET");
        $oauth->setToken($req_token['oauth_token'], $req_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        print_r($req_token);
        $acc_token = $oauth->getAccessToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token", null, '2b875b97', "GET");
        print_r($acc_token);
    ?>
```

Получаю фаталку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect) in /home/vagrant/html/project2/index.php on line 21
```

Чувствую, что как-то замешна `verified_token`, я его вбил вручную из аккаунта после первичной авторизации (`2b875b97`). Не знаю что делать, подскажите в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: в примерах `scope=email_r%20transactions_r` "%20" обозначает пробел, а у вас остальные скоупы отделены "&" . Может и их тоже "%20" отделить?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov не помогает((